# Is "to reach more" idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-choice, idiomatic-language

Let's suppose someone's goal is to get a better job, better salary and so on. Would it be idiomatic for them to say:

> I want **to reach more** than I have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Closest options I can think of are:

> I want to reach **further** than I have now

or

> I want to **achieve** more than I have now